# MySQL create table from txt file

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a mysql table from a thesaurus text file I got off project gutenberg; however, I'm having some issues doing it. I was able to write the following script which successfully creates a table with the information:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/mthesaur.txt'

    INTO TABLE thesaurus_entries

    COLUMNS
        TERMINATED BY ','

    LINES

        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

In the text file, the first word is the thesaurus entry, and it is followed by all its synonyms separated by commas. Each entry is separated by a line break.

My problem is that I was originally going to use just one table with a large number of columns, but I can't figure out how to easily make 100+ columns for the synonyms. I tried doing this:

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE PROCEDURE ABC()

   BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;
        ALTER TABLE `thesaurus`.`thesaurus_entries` ADD COLUMN a 
VARCHAR(60) NULL  AFTER `thesaurus_entries_id` ;
         IF a=100 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$
```

But all that did was add one column named "a" instead of adding 100 columns named "1, 2, 3, etc."

If it were easy to make the table as a key value pair (with separate tables for each word's synomyms), I'd be willing to go that route, but I can't figure out how to do that from a txt file.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want a table with hundreds of columns.  Instead, you probably want just two columns, `word` and `synonym`.  Each row in your input file will generate (potentially) multiple rows in your table.

You could write a simple preprocessor (in your favorite scripting language) to convert your input file to a list of word,synonym pairs.  Then load it as you are doing now.

Comment: That does sound like a good idea. Unfortunately I'm still learning programming in general, so when you say "your favorite scripting language" my mind draws a blank! I know how to use basic Java, Spring, MySQL, JSP, CSS, a little javascript, but not much on the simple scripting language front.

Comment: Do it in Java then.  Write a program that reads in a line, splits it on `,`, then for each element after the first, print the first element and that element.

Comment: I actually managed to do it! It was probably a lot more complex than it needed to be, but I got it all working. Now I have a 2.5 million row table in my database.